# Creating a button labeled with one PHP item to insert another

Tags: php, button, field

Very simply, I'm creating a PHP content database for a website. I want to create buttons next to a text field, with a title drawn from a table. Clicking this button then inserts an equivalent code into the field. These PHP table consists of three columns: key, word and code

So far I have the following code... this DOES populate the button value, but the does not insert the code. I suspect this is due to the use of `''` within the PHP code. Am I correct?

Appreciate any guidance

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function insertText(elemID, text)
      {
        var elem = document.getElementById(elemID);
        elem.innerHTML += text;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form>
    <textarea id="txt1"></textarea>
    <input type="button" value="<?php echo $row_tooltips['word']; ?>" onclick="insertText('txt1', '<?php echo $row_tooltips['code']; ?>');">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function insertText(elemID, text)
      {
        var elem = document.getElementById(elemID);
        elem.innerHTML += text;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form>
<?php
$row_tooltips['word'] = "buttontitle";
$row_tooltips['code'] = "code";
?>
    <textarea id="txt1"></textarea>
    <input type="button" value="<?php echo $row_tooltips['word']; ?>" onclick="insertText('txt1', '<?php echo $row_tooltips['code']; ?>');">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Changed nothing of your code but predefining the $row_tooltips array and it works completely fine for me. Are you sure, that this array gets filled correctly?

greetz

Comment: I see what you've done there but now all I get is 'buttontitle' and 'code' rather than the items from the PHP recordset.

Comment: Alright, that's good. That means that the problem occurs already at the point where you are filling your database values into the $row_tooltips['code'] array OR there is just nothing in the database either. But since this part isn't included in your code example I cannot tell you exactly what it is.

Comment: you're entirely right... the code was a brief line of html code, changed it to plaintext and it worked... What I'm trying to achieve is a button to insert some HTML code though so when the user hits a button a full link is included into a PHP text field.

Answer (score 0):

So you say:

> What I'm trying to achieve is a button to insert some HTML code though so when the user hits a button a full link is included into a PHP text field.

Then indeed, if there is an ' in the string that has been echoed, your script breaks. Also with any other htmlspecialchars, especially " your run into problems; So you need to escape that.

Also, htmlcode inside a textarea is standard not possible, so you should probably make it a div (with an textbox inside, if you need that).

Based on your original code, below a code that works ok. I use `htmlspecialchars` for the plain text, and `addslashes` for your html with (the ', as encoding them does not work).

```
<?php
    // Remove this, only for testing
    $row_tooltips['word'] = "Insert a FooBar";
    $row_tooltips['code'] = "<h1>Delicious 'FooBar'</h1><img src=\"http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/reep-chocolade-12835946.jpg\" alt=\"foobar\" />";
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function insertText(elemID, text)
          {
            var elem = document.getElementById(elemID);
            elem.innerHTML += text;
          }
     </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <div id="txt1"></div>
        <input type="button" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row_tooltips['word'], ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-1'); ?>" 
            onclick="insertText('txt1', '<?php echo addslashes(htmlspecialchars($row_tooltips['code'], ENT_COMPAT, 'ISO-8859-1')); ?>');">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Tested in Chrome.